# Twitter Bootstrap : vertically align child div with height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap v3.1.1 to design web app. I hav three divs in the middle div i have a small div and i need to place it vertically aligned.

Here is what i got so far.

```
    <body>
        <div class="row fill">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-1 fill" style="background-color:red;">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 parent" style="background-color:blue;">
            <div class="child"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-1 fill" style="background-color:green;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

I couldn't place the child div vertically aligned. I tried following css.

```
    .parent {
        display:table;   
        height:100%;    
        display:table;table-layout:fixed;
    }


    .child {
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
        border:2px solid gray;
        height:40%;
    }
```

Someone please help,
Thanks.

Comment: I have create a [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/RuTpZqh8N2) here based on your code. Could you explain what needs to be vertically center aligned?

Comment: Actually div with class name "child". Please remove display:table-cell; from the  class

Comment: Ah, I think I get what you mean, how about [this](http://www.bootply.com/6D9nCEjr11)?

Comment: thanku..thanku.. Please put it as answer. I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem was you wanted to vertically center-align a child div whose `height` was `40%` but since you had given it as `display:table-cell`, it behaves like a `<td>` element and ignores the height.

The solution is to place that child div in another container and apply the `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` to that container:

```
    <div class="row fill">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-1 fill" style="background-color:red;">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 parent" style="background-color:blue;">
        <!-- another container to vertical align the child div -->
        <div class="center-child">
         <div class="child">test</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-1 fill" style="background-color:green;">

        </div>
    </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/agTlcKTzdo)**